# CodeIgniter and Bootstrap3 Integration Base_URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to integrate the Bootstrap 3 in my CodeIgniter. I have latest versions of CodeIgniter and Bootstrap 3. Here's how the directory tree looks like:

Project Name

```
-application
----views
--------home.php
-dist (from Bootstrap3)
-system
```

Now I've configured my `config.php` and `autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form','url','html');
```

Problem now is when I'm trying to copy one of the templates in Bootstrap 3 just to try out if it's working, it will just display plain HTML. I think the problem is this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" >
<script src="<?php base_url()?>../../dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php base_url()?>../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Am I doing this right? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: try removing ../../ after base_url()

Comment: can you please also post the value of your base_url in config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `base_url()` is `localhost/your_root_diractory_name` ,if u are in local server.
This should Help.If you are in linux server there may be permission issue

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>dist/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this also didn't work. Yes, its local.

Comment: can you post ur base_url()?? and what is your os?